# I cannot change the suffix below the product price

Tags: html, price

I have no knowledge of php but I created a code to show description of parcels below the price.

My code is calculating several decimal places and is not showing the default currency, which in my case, is in Reais (BR).

I would like you to help me. Thank you very much.

```
//Adiciona sufixo parcelas abaixo do preço
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'add_price_suffix', 99, 4 );

function add_price_suffix( $suffix, $product, $parcel_price) {
    $parcel_price = $product-> get_price() /6;
    $suffix = "<p>Ou até 6x de $parcel_price sem juros</p>". '<br />';
    return $suffix;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yu3P.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`round`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function and round the price to two decimal values:

```
$parcel_price = $product-> get_price() /6;
$parcel_price = round($parcel_price, 2);
$suffix = "<p>Ou até 6x de $parcel_price sem juros</p>". '<br />';
return $suffix;
```